# Passing multiple values to PTY terminal

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, pty

I'm attempting to use ruby to interact with a CLI which takes multiple values using PTY. However, I can only get the pseudo-terminal generated by PTY to see the first value I pass. Test scripts below:

**test.rb**

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

def till_prompt(cout, prompt)
  buffer = ""
  regexPrompt = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(prompt))
  loop { buffer << cout.getc.chr; break if buffer =~ regexPrompt }
  puts "buffer: \n" + buffer + "\nend of buffer\n"
  return buffer
end

$expect_verbose = true
PTY.spawn("ruby inputTest.rb") do |output, input, pid|

  till_prompt(output, "1: ")
  input.printf("hello\n\rworld\n\r")

  till_prompt(output, "2: ")
  input.printf("world\n\r")
end
```

**inputTest.rb**

```
require 'highline/import'

word1 = ask("1: ")
word2 =  ask("2: ")
word3 =  ask("3: ")

system "echo '#{word1}\n#{word2}' > test.log"
puts "#{word1}\n#{word2}"
```

**$ > cat test.log**

```
hello
```

I can't figure out why it is only picking up the first response.

P.S. I know expect can be used here, but I replaced it with a custom function to have more control over what was going on for debugging purposes.